# guess_dates() missing from linelist package

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the `guess_dates()` function from the `linelist` package and I'm receiving this error:

> *Error: 'guess_dates' is not an exported object from 'namespace:linelist'*

I've tried restarting R and updating all packages without luck. When I query the function using ??`guess_dates`, the Help page returns

> "no results found."

This package::function() combo linelist::guess_dates() is widely referenced by [other R users](https://r4epis.netlify.app/training/r_basics/dates/).

Any ideas?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the package using `devtools::install_github("reconhub/linelist")`  mentioned on the [GitHub](https://github.com/reconhub/linelist). Here is a reproducible example which worked when installing the package:

```r
devtools::install_github("reconhub/linelist")
#> Skipping install of 'linelist' from a github remote, the SHA1 (cae034de) has not changed since last install.
#>   Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
library(linelist)
linelist::guess_dates(c("03 Jan 2018", "07/03/1982", "08/20/85"))
#> [1] "2018-01-03" "1982-03-07" "1985-08-20"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>